# Why doesn't FontAwesome "flip" animation work in React?

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, react-font-awesome, font-awesome-6

I'm adding individual icons explicitly as shown here:
https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/use-with/react/add-icons#add-some-style

The code I'm using is:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faRocket } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons' 

...
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faRocket} flip />
...
```

It seems like most of the other animations work. When I replace 'flip' with 'spin', for example, the icon spins. I can't get it to flip.

Also worth mentioning, when I wrote the code like this:

`<i class="fa-solid fa-rocket fa-flip"></i>`

The flip animation worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a closer look to the `FontAwesomeIcon` component you'll see all the props it can receive and what are the expected values for them.

In the case of `flip` it only takes three posible values but you need to specify which one you wanna use, otherwise It won't work.

As an example, your component would look like this:

`<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faRocket} flip='vertical' />`

[image: fontawesome props]